# Is "Oops: ; return error;" a valid method declaration in C?

Tags: ios, c, syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <AssertMacros.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int error = 1;

    verify_noerr( error );
    require_noerr( error, Oops );  //<---- Is Oops a callback method?

    printf("You shouldn't be here!\n");

Oops: ;                    // <--v____  Is this a method declaration?
    return error;          // <--^        Why the ':' followed by the ';'?
}
```

This code is from [iOS documentation from 2006](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1431/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003934/). I realize that in C the default return type for a method with no declared return type is int. But is this really a method that is leaning on that principle? And why the colon semicolon? My last thought was that its a C block, but [Wikipedia says otherwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29).

I'm stumped.

Comment: It's a goto label, with a statement after it to be valid.

Comment: It's basically the same as `case X:` in a `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Oops: ;
```

is a label, which can be the target of a `goto`.

I'm guessing that `require_noerr` is a macro that expands to a `goto` to the given label if `error` is an error code.

You'd use this system to exit from a function when an error occurred.  It allows for cleanup code between the label and the end of the function (which a simple `if (error) return;` doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

this is called a label in C programming.

in c code you can use goto to jump to this label

```
goto Oops;
```